# How to append to a string with a DTS variable in c#

Tags: c#, xml, ssis

hei,

My goal is to append SSIS variable to piece of string (which is XML from a service).

i have this piece of code that i have tried:

```
string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stm.GetBuffer());
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(xml + "<CC>" + Dts.Variables["User::XX"].Value.ToString() + "</CC>");
```

But it will not append the DTS.Variable at all (*edit AND neither the CC-element)

Is there some error in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct regarding the DTS variable reference. However, you should consider use several calls to the Append() method to be able to debug properly.

Also consider using a clear syntax such as :

```
String xx = (String)Dts.Variables["User::XX"].Value;
xx = "<CC>" + xx + "</CC>"; //not very clean should use xml types instead
sb.Append(xml).Append(xx);
```

Hth,
G.R.